# View the text or the sender of a deleted message in telethon

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, python-telegram-bot, telethon

Using telethon docs, I managed to write a code that could get the ID of a deleted message. But how can I use that? Can I get the name/id or any info about the person that sent it? If not, can I at least view what the text that was deleted is or anything that could get me to know the sender

I 'm aware that it works only with channels and can get me a channel ID like `1001586` or something, But I just want to view the deleted text at least>

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='[%(levelname) 5s/%(asctime)s] %(name)s: %(message)s',
                    level=logging.WARNING)

api_id=******
api_hash='*******'
client=TelegramClient('*****', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.MessageDeleted)
async def handler(event):
    # Log all deleted message IDs
    for msg_id in event.deleted_ids:
        print('Message', msg_id, 'was deleted in', event.chat_id,event.user_id)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: Telegram doesn't send the `Message` object that was deleted, only the `id` so that you can delete it from your database or chat view (imagine a real application).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no way to read the deleted Message :(

But you can save the messages runtime with its id in a file and later create a simple python script to compare both the ids to get the delete Message,